# How to divide FOR loop in N even parts for parallel execution given constant input data for each iteration?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a time consuming loop I would like to execute in parallel.
Pseudocode:

```
for(int n = 0; n < 2048; n++)
{
  output_data[n] = function(constant_input_data, n)
}
```

- Input data for each iteration is completely the same
- Output for Nth iteration is stored in array with index N.

How to divide this loop in C equal parts, where C is CPU core count?

What is the best and the most elegant way to do this in C#, .net?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx) of TPL

```
Parallel.For( 0, 2048, n=>
   {
         output_data[n] = function(constant_input_data, n);
    });
```

TPL tries to spawn as many threads as the no. of cpu cores you have and then your work is divided in tasks that are scheduled on those threads. So it is 2048 tasks on *possibly* x no. of threads where x is no. of cores.

Comment: Will this divide the loop in 4 equal parts for each core? How does Parallel.For work?

Comment: yep ... do it the .net-4.0-way :) ... core counting is legacy stuff :)

Comment: @JBeurer and much more - it even uses the task-stealing functionality of .net 4.0 if one core gets idle (and much more like prediction ...) :)

Comment: Thanks, this indeed looks like a very simple and elegant solution, just what I needed.

Comment: @jbeurer It is not guaranteed that the loop will be divided in equal parts. For such advanced scenario you will need to implement custom partitioning. see http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/philpenn/Speeding-up-ParallelFor-using-the-Range-Partitioner

Comment: Timing improvement with Parallel.For 14703 ms down from
46004ms on quad core. Nice!

Comment: @Pratik the range-partitioning can only be used, if a `Count` or `Length` property is available. Otherwise there are other mechanisms to detect a potential partitioning!